# access property from another class

Tags: ios, swift, class

I have a custom swift class like this

```
class NichedHelper: NSObject {
    private var _theController:UIViewController? = nil
    var theController:UIViewController? {
        get {
            return self._theController
        }
        set {
            self._theController = newValue
            }
        }...
```

it has an implementation function like this and `_theController` passing a Lobb class that inherit UIViewController

```
func DoPump(from: String, theBoard: CGRect, overide: Bool) {
    let abil:AnyObject = _theController!
    abil.bottomConst.constant = -80
}
```

it throw error `'AnyObject' does not have a member named 'bottomConst'`.

since i don't know what the english word for this kind of technique, so that will be my first question.

my second question, is it possible if i am sure Lobb class (or other class) have a variable called bottomConst, how can i access it from class NichedHelper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i change from passing the `UIViewController` to `NSLayoutConstraint`

Answer (score 0):

you have declared the _theController as private , remove that just declare as

```
var _theController:UIViewController!
```

// this is how we roll in swift ;) bye bye Objective-C

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you are trying to do and why you have two `UIViewController` instances. So I'm not able to answer your first question but regarding your second one, you have to cast the object to a `UIViewController` object:

```
func DoPump(from: String, theBoard: CGRect, overide: Bool) {
  let abil:AnyObject = _theController as! UIViewController
  abil.bottomConst.constant = -80
}
```

This at least should make the compiling error away, if you have the `bottomConst` attribute declared as a variable of `UIViewControllers` in an `extension` (since they do not have this variable normally.